# How to disable static tls with mingw32 gcc?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mingw

I am building a win32 dll using mingw32 and gcc (tdmgcc32 9.2.0), that is a plugin to an existing, win32 exe. But when the exe tries to load it, an access violation occurs within the LoadLibraryA() call. The stack trace shows:

```
    ntdll.dll!LdrpAllocateTlsEntry()
    ntdll.dll!LdrpHandleTlsData()
    ntdll.dll!LdrpDoPostSnapWork()
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpSnapModule@4()
    ntdll.dll!LdrpProcessWork()
    ntdll!LdrpDrawinWorkQueue()
    ntdll!LdrpLoadDllInternal()
    ntdll!LdrLoadDll()
    KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryExW()
    KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryA()
```

In trying to understand this, I came across [this note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format):

> Statically declared TLS data objects can be used only in statically loaded image files. This fact makes it unreliable to use static TLS data in a DLL unless you know that the DLL, or anything statically linked with it, will never be loaded dynamically with the LoadLibrary API function.

And [additionally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/thread-local-storage-tls?view=msvc-170):

> On Windows operating systems before Windows Vista, __declspec( thread ) has some limitations. If a DLL declares any data or object as __declspec( thread ), it can cause a protection fault if dynamically loaded. ...

(Now, I am using Windows 10, but the exe that is loading the dll was built for Windows 2000)

Continuing to investigate, I found [KB118816](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/118816) that restates the issue, but adds:

> To determine whether a DLL uses static TLS, the Dumpbin.exe tool can be used to dump the header information. A DLL has static TLS if the OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES contains a size that is greater than 0 (zero) in the Thread Storage Directory

And running dumpbin /headers on my dll confirmed it had static TLS data:

```
30004 [      18] RVA [size] of Thread Storage Directory
```

Now, none of my code in the dll uses `__declspec(thread)`, and in fact the TLS data is the same size when I build an empty dll; so I presume this is being used for std initialization or something.

So my question is: **how can I prevent gcc generating static TLS data?** is there a compile option to make it generate code that uses `TlsAlloc()` or something instead?

The compile flags I am using right now are:

```
-W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -masm=att -fno-pcc-struct-return -mms-bitfields
```

And the flags to dllwrap/ld:

```
--target i386-mingw32 -mwindows -mdll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base
```

**Update:**

I found that this exact situation I describe is detailed in [MinGW bug 1557](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1557/) from 2011, which was closed without being addressed as "out of date". In the comments, Cesar Strauss identifies libmingw32.a as the source of the static tls data, and I have confirmed that is still the case in my situation.

> This is exactly what happened to my DLLs. My hook DLL is being loaded at the start time of any executable (via LoadPerProcess registry entry), and in some cases loading my DLL will trigger a segmentation fault (Windows will hide this fault, thus user won't observe it). However, the functionality of my DLL will be, obviously, missing.
>
> ...
>
> Unfortunately, some runtime (I think libgcc.a, have to do more research here) already contains several (four?) TLS variables, thus any DLL built by mingw will contain a .tls section.
>
> ...
>
> I suspect the mingw runtime is the culprit, instead:
>
> `````
> tlsmcrt.o: file format pe-i386
> tlsmthread.o: file format pe-i386
> tlssup.o: file format pe-i386
> 6 .tls$AAA 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000fa6 2**2
> 7 .tls$ZZZ 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000faa 2**2
> 10 .tls 00000018 00000000 00000000 00000fb6 2**2
> tlsthrd.o: file format pe-i386````
> `````

I also discovered through more debugging and experimentation why I was only experiencing the problem sporadically: the LoadLibrary() failure only occurs when the dll cannot be loaded at its default base address and is relocated.

**Conclusion:**

I can see three possible solutions to this:

1. build my own libmingw32.a that does not use `__declspec(thread)` somehow.
2. move the entire project over to visual c++ where (whether by design or by luck) this situation does not arise, because static TLS is not used.
3. pick a base address for the dll that is less likely to clash, and keep my fingers crossed.

In the context where this project will be deployed, (1) is too unmanageable to be viable, (2) is quite painful, and (3) has a high chance of success. Sucks to be relying on a dice roll when deploying software, but it is the option that is the best fit at the moment.

Comment: it is usually enough to build with [-shared](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/mingw/dll.html). maybe just use it instead of all other flags and check if the dll is built ok and re-add flags needed one by one to figure what is causing the trouble?

Comment: i inherited this project, so im not sure exactly why it uses dllwrap and those linker flags. but yeah, i already tried changing that to invoke `gcc -shared …` for the link step, and it made no difference—which makes sense, because how the tls is set up is a compile decision; the linker just puts the tls table in if the objects require it.

Comment: [dllwrap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/x86_64-w64-mingw32-dllwrap.1.html) says: `dllwrap - Ancient tool for generating PE style dll's. dllwrap is deprecated.  You should not use it for any new code.  Use ld --shared instead.` you can probably start with trivial hello world dll to check if it is built correctly with shared and add specific flags and stages to it to see what breaks it.

Comment: yeah, it is a problem even with a trivial example. i have already been through that process to eliminate any of the compiler flags i was using or libraries i was linking to as the culprit

Comment: The `tlssup.o` object shouldn't be getting linked into your program unless you reference a symbol from it (either directly or indirectly).  You could actually use the GNU archiver utility (`ar`) to remove `tlssup.o` from `libmingw32.a`, which should be much simpler than recompiling MinGW.  I think it would also be good to compile an empty DLL and look at the map file generated by the linker to see exactly what symbols are defined in the static TLS area and which object those symbols came from.

Comment: @DavidGrayson that is a good idea, thank you! i will try that out when i next have the opportunity to work on this project.